# How to produce random hex color in sql?

Tags: sql, random, hex

It's pretty hard topic for me because SQL is not my best skill ;)

I must insert random hex colors into database row. How can I do it? Is it possible to create function that will draw numbers?

Comment: Which database? (MySQL, oracle, postgresql, ...)

Comment: Yeah, which database?

Comment: I assumed it was MySQL since he responded to the first answer with something about MySQL a couple days after it was posted.

Answer (score 34):

```
SET [Color] =  '#' +  CONVERT(VARCHAR(max), CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(3), 2)
```

Answer (score 22):

Here is the logic explained below wrapped in a function for MySQL. It's very easy to use.

```
mysql> select random_color();
+----------------+
| random_color() |
+----------------+
| #8F50B4        |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

It can be called over and over again and each time it will have a different color.

```
CREATE FUNCTION `random_color`() RETURNS char(7) CHARSET latin1 DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
 DECLARE str CHAR(7);
 SET str = concat('#',SUBSTRING((lpad(hex(round(rand() * 10000000)),6,0)),-6));
 RETURN str;
END;
```

This will give you six digit hex number codes in MySQL

```
SELECT concat('#',SUBSTRING((lpad(hex(round(rand() * 10000000)),6,0)),-6))
```

Here's a great one that will give you incremental colors

```
SELECT *, 
       concat('#',SUBSTRING((lpad(hex(@curRow := @curRow + 10),6,0)),-6)) AS color 
FROM table 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT @curRow := 5426175) color_start_point
```

Answer (score 4):

This works for me in **MySQL:**

```
mysql> SELECT CONCAT('#',LPAD(CONV(ROUND(RAND()*16777215),10,16),6,0)) AS color;
+---------+
| color   |
+---------+
| #0E74A9 |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

*Short explanation:*

- 16777215 is the maximum 24 bit unsigned integer, that is: 2<sup>24</sup>-1
- Multiplied by `RAND()` and `ROUND()`'ed gives a random unsigned integer in the RGB color range: (0, 2<sup>24</sup>-1)
- Then, convert from base 10 to base 16 to get hexadecimal
- `LPAD()` to zero-fill by left
- And finally, `CONCAT()` to get the `'#'` character

Answer (score 2):

```
with cte1 as (
select round(round(rand(),1)*15,0) as hex1,
 round(round(rand(),1)*15,0) as hex2,
 round(round(rand(),1)*15,0) as hex3,
 round(round(rand(),1)*15,0) as hex4,
 round(round(rand(),1)*15,0) as hex5,
 round(round(rand(),1)*15,0) as hex6
),
cte2 as (
select case when hex1 = 10 then 'A' 
when hex1 = 11 then 'B'
when hex1 = 12 then 'C'
when hex1 = 13 then 'D'
when hex1 = 14 then 'E'
when hex1 = 15 then 'F'
else str(hex1) end as hex1h,
case when hex2 = 10 then 'A' 
when hex2 = 11 then 'B'
when hex2 = 12 then 'C'
when hex2 = 13 then 'D'
when hex2 = 14 then 'E'
when hex2 = 15 then 'F'
else str(hex2) end as hex2h,
case when hex3 = 10 then 'A' 
when hex3 = 11 then 'B'
when hex3 = 12 then 'C'
when hex3 = 13 then 'D'
when hex3 = 14 then 'E'
when hex3 = 15 then 'F'
else str(hex3) end as hex3h,
case when hex4 = 10 then 'A' 
when hex4 = 11 then 'B'
when hex4 = 12 then 'C'
when hex4 = 13 then 'D'
when hex4 = 14 then 'E'
when hex4 = 15 then 'F'
else str(hex4) end as hex4h,
case when hex5 = 10 then 'A' 
when hex5 = 11 then 'B'
when hex5 = 12 then 'C'
when hex5 = 13 then 'D'
when hex5 = 14 then 'E'
when hex5 = 15 then 'F'
else str(hex5) end as hex5h,
case when hex6 = 10 then 'A' 
when hex6 = 11 then 'B'
when hex6 = 12 then 'C'
when hex6 = 13 then 'D'
when hex6 = 14 then 'E'
when hex6 = 15 then 'F'
else str(hex6) end as hex6h from cte1)

select '#'+ltrim(hex1h)+ltrim(hex2h)+ltrim(hex3h)+ltrim(hex4h)+ltrim(hex5h)+ltrim(hex6h) from cte2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a SQL Server Function which works in all versions from 2012 onwards that generates random HTML colour codes in hex format, i.e. #AABB00. It requires a View as well, which is also provided below.

The Function gives you the option to avoid light or dark colours, which can be useful if you are trying to generate background and foreground colours that won't clash too badly (i.e. dark text on a dark background).

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Get_Random_Colour (@intStyle tinyint = 0)  
RETURNS varchar(7)

/*
* Purpose:      Returns the HTML colour code for a random colour
* Inputs:       @intStyle - 0: does not filter the colour range
*                           1: avoid dark colours
*                           2: avoid light colours
*/

AS  
BEGIN 

DECLARE @c1 char(2), @c2 char(2), @c3 char(2)
DECLARE @i1 tinyint, @i2 tinyint, @i3 tinyint
DECLARE @strResult As varchar(255)
DECLARE @intLow tinyint = 0
DECLARE @intHigh tinyint = 255

IF @intStyle = 1
    SET @intLow = 80

IF @intStyle = 2
    SET @intHigh = 140


--Generate random numbers
SELECT @i1 = CAST(ROUND((@intHigh-@intLow) * RandNumber + @intLow,0) as int) from dbo.vRandNumber
SELECT @i2 = CAST(ROUND((@intHigh-@intLow) * RandNumber + @intLow,0) as int) from dbo.vRandNumber
SELECT @i3 = CAST(ROUND((@intHigh-@intLow) * RandNumber + @intLow,0) as int) from dbo.vRandNumber

--Convert them to hex format
SELECT @c1 = FORMAT(@i1, 'X')
SELECT @c2 = FORMAT(@i2, 'X')
SELECT @c3 = FORMAT(@i3, 'X')

--Pad them to two characters
SELECT @strResult = '#' 
    + REPLICATE('0', 2-LEN(@c1)) + @c1
    + REPLICATE('0', 2-LEN(@c2)) + @c2
    + REPLICATE('0', 2-LEN(@c3)) + @c3



RETURN @strResult

END
GO
```

And here is the View that the Function is dependent on:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vRandNumber]
AS
SELECT RAND() as RandNumber
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which DBMS are you using, but this solution is applied on SQL Server, and could be applied on a different DBMS if you know the corresponding syntax and functions.

(I will try to be as brief as I can in this)

Hex colors are basically a hexadecimal `VARBINARY` values which is supported by almost all DBMS. You only need the right conversion to bind it to your needs.

For example, if we cast a string `foo` as `VARBINARY` it'll return the value of `0x666F6F` and if we cast back to `VARCHAR` it'll return `foo`

```
SELECT CAST('foo' AS VARBINARY) 
-- Returns : 0x666F6F

SELECT CAST(0x666F6F AS VARCHAR)
-- Returns : foo
```

So, it's the same value with corresponded datatype even if the output is different. This is also applied in colors (hex to rgb, rgb to hex, hex to binary and so on).

Now, you know that Hex colors are using `VARBINARY` datatype, which will be our target in this solution.

The first thing is to generate that  `VARBINARY` by using RGB values (which is another datatype of INT values). RGB values are three different values representing Red, Green, and Blue. The minimum number of each of them is 0 and the max is 255. So, if we do `RGB(0,0,0)` this will return `#000000` (black) and `RGB(255,255,255)` returns `#FFFFFF` (white).

Oh, I forgot, you don't need any special equation in this conversion since DBMS is already handling this.

So, your first target is to do a function which takes RGB values (with min 0 and max 255) and then convert it to Hexadecimal `VARBINARY`, which will gives you the Hex color.

To Convert from RGB to Hex, you will need to know each 2 hexadecimal represent an RGB Value. For instance `#BA55D3` is corresponded to `rgb(186,85,211)`
The actual hexadecimal for it is

- **R** = 0xBA
- **G** = 0x55
- **B** = 0xD3

WHERE

- 0xBA = 186
- 0x55 = 18
- 0xD3 = 211

. So, from each Hex color, you'll need to divide it into 3 groups of two values to represent RGB values.

If you cast 0xBA as INT it'll give you 186 which is the value of the red part.

```
 SELECT 
    CAST(0xBA AS INT) 
    -- Returns : 186
```

the same thing applies to the rest.

Now, we need our function to do the work for us, for this,  I have created a function that simply takes three int values and convert them into `VARBINARY` which helps me to convert it back to varchar to just format the output into a hex color value.

```
CREATE FUNCTION RGBToHex
(
        @R          INT,
        @G          INT,
        @B          INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(7)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE 
        @VarR       VARBINARY,
        @VarG       VARBINARY,
        @VarB       VARBINARY,

        @Result     VARCHAR(7)

SELECT 
     @VarR  = CONVERT(VARBINARY, @R) * 1 , 
     @VarG  = CONVERT(VARBINARY, @G) * 1 , 
     @VarB  = CONVERT(VARBINARY, @B) * 1

SET @Result = '#' + SUBSTRING(Convert(VARCHAR(MAX),@VarR, 1), 3, 2) + SUBSTRING(Convert(VARCHAR(MAX),@VarG, 1), 3, 2) + SUBSTRING(Convert(VARCHAR(MAX),@VarB, 1), 3, 2)


    RETURN @Result

END
```

Example :

```
SELECT 
    RGBToHex(186,85,211)
-- Returns : #BA55D3
```

Now, the function is ready to be used, all we need is a way to randomize three INTs inside this function, to get a random color each time, taking the minimum and maximum (0-255) values for RGB in mind.

IN SQL Server I used a recursive query for the sake of simplicity, you could do your own query with your own method or function.

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT 
        ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % 256 AS R , 
        ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % 256 AS G ,
        ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % 256 AS B
)   
SELECT 
    dbo.RGBToHex(R,G,B)
FROM CTE
```

In the query above I have set the random number between 0-255 for each column, then I just put these values inside the function to generate a new color.

If you need a reversed function that takes color's hexadecimal and return RGB value, you could use this function :

```
CREATE FUNCTION HexToRGB
(
        @Hex        VARCHAR(7)   
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE 

        @VarH       VARCHAR(6), 
        @R          INT, 
        @G          INT, 
        @B          INT,
        @Result     VARCHAR(100)

SET @VarH = (CASE WHEN LEFT(@Hex, 1) = '#' THEN SUBSTRING(@Hex, 2,6) ELSE @Hex END)

SELECT
    @R  =   CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARBINARY, '0x' +  SUBSTRING(@VarH, 1,2), 1) ),
    @G  =   CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARBINARY, '0x' +  SUBSTRING(@VarH, 3,2), 1) ),
    @B  =   CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARBINARY, '0x' +  SUBSTRING(@VarH, 5,2), 1) )

SET @Result = 'rgb('    + CAST(@R AS VARCHAR(3) ) + ',' + CAST(@G AS VARCHAR(3) )   +  ','  +   CAST(@B AS VARCHAR(3) )     + ')' 

    RETURN @Result

END
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL

```
select concat("#", conv(round(rand() * 255), 10, 16), conv(round(rand() * 255), 10, 16), conv(round(rand() * 255), 10, 16));
```

Comment: Does not always produce output with 6 characters behind the #.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution for PostgreSQL.

```sql
SELECT concat('#',lpad(to_hex(round(random() * 10000000)::int4),6,'0'))
```

I used it to set the random color to `Color` field of the table using that code:

```sql
UPDATE "MyTable" SET "Color" = concat('#',lpad(to_hex(round(random() * 10000000)::int8),6,'0'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess you need to use rand - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand - i.e.

```
INSERT INTO ... VALUES ( ... , ROUND(RAND(255 * 255 * 255)), ...)
```

Comment: Two issues: i need hex format - how to rand letters? How to change it to function returns 6 length number instead rand every digit?

Comment: Can you just look up the string function `HEX` to do the conversion?

Answer (score 0):

**For all SQL queries(MySql, SQL Server, etc) this method will work**

In sql we can generate random colors using the `substring` function. Keep in mind that in sql charecter index starts from **1** (**not 0** like javascript)

```
select concat('#',substring('0123456789ABCDEF',round(rand() * 15)+1,1),substring('0123456789ABCDEF',round(rand() * 15)+1,1),substring('0123456789ABCDEF',round(rand() * 15)+1,1),substring('0123456789ABCDEF',round(rand() * 15)+1,1),substring('0123456789ABCDEF',round(rand() * 15)+1,1),substring('0123456789ABCDEF',round(rand() * 15)+1,1));
```

Where `round(rand() * 15)` gives a random number between 0 and 15 including 0 and 15. Thats why we are adding 1 to it to get 1 as minimum value for the substring index

## To get only Light Colors :-

```
select concat('#',substring('0123456789ABCDEF',round(rand() * 8)+8,1),substring('0123456789ABCDEF',round(rand() * 15)+1,1),substring('0123456789ABCDEF',round(rand() * 8)+8,1),substring('0123456789ABCDEF',round(rand() * 15)+1,1),substring('0123456789ABCDEF',round(rand() * 8)+8,1),substring('0123456789ABCDEF',round(rand() * 15)+1,1));
```

## To get only Dark Colors :-

```
select concat('#',substring('0123456789ABCDEF',round(rand() * 7)+1,1),substring('0123456789ABCDEF',round(rand() * 15)+1,1),substring('0123456789ABCDEF',round(rand() * 7)+1,1),substring('0123456789ABCDEF',round(rand() * 15)+1,1),substring('0123456789ABCDEF',round(rand() * 7)+1,1),substring('0123456789ABCDEF',round(rand() * 15)+1,1));
```

### Update:-

In all the above cases we can use a temporary variable to have the repeating range value to minimize the query like

```
set @r='0123456789ABCDEF';
select concat('#',substring(@r,round(rand() * 15)+1,1),substring(@r,round(rand() * 15)+1,1),substring(@r,round(rand() * 15)+1,1),substring(@r,round(rand() * 15)+1,1),substring(@r,round(rand() * 15)+1,1),substring(@r,round(rand() * 15)+1,1));
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it for BigQuery. With an INT column called "section":

```sql
SELECT section
, ifNull(concat('#'
    , format('%X', mod(section, 256))
    , format('%X', mod(div(section, 256), 256))
    , format('%X', mod(div(div(section, 256), 256), 256))
    ), '#000000' #black=default
  ) as html_color
FROM StopTimes;
```

And as a bonus, with section being a string column it looks like this:

```sql
SELECT section, ifNull(concat('#'
    , format('%X', mod(abs(farm_fingerprint(section)), 256))
    , format('%X', mod(abs(div(farm_fingerprint(section), 256)), 256))
    , format('%X', mod(abs(div(div(farm_fingerprint(section), 256), 256)), 256))
    ), '#000000' #black=default
  ) as html_color
FROM StopTimes;
```